# How to hide evaluated code in Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When debugging Chrome shows evaluated code:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: I guess `Display variable values inline while debugging` in devtools settings for Sources.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks, post  it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open [Settings](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#settings) and uncheck the `Display variable values inline while debugging` option.

[image: Display variable values inline while debugging]